# Accessing URL parameters on MVC framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult Edit(string param)
{

}
```

http://localhost/Edit/5,someothervalue,etc

How can i reach 'param' from a global function. Basically I am trying to access the parameter in my url from a statinc method that I am building which will be global. That method breaks down the parameter and returns id and other things that I am passing inside param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a way to get the route values from a given URL. Here's some code that might help you do this with a URL string. Just note that I put a IRouteRegistrant interface that just has a Register function that takes a route collection. Basically replace that with your registration mechanism.

```
public static RouteData GetRouteValues(IRouteRegistrant registrant, string url)
{
      var routes = new RouteCollection();
      registrant.Register(routes);

      var context = new FakeHttpContext(url);
      return routes.GetRouteData(context);
}
```

So to get at the values (for your param example) you just need the following:

```
public static void MyFn()
{
     var values = GetRouteValues(....., "~/Edit/5");
     var paramValue = values.Values["param"];
     .....
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This code comes from the XUnit examples. Download the latest release to get the full code.